# Excel dynamic lookup

Tags: formula

I have a table that I need to populate whether a person has finished training or not. The headers are all the training classes, and Column A is the name of every one. I have another table with all the names and classes and if they are certified or not. I need to make a formula that can easily check if they have been certified or not and enter an "X" if they have or stay blank if not. The lookup table has 3 columns in it, 1 is the name, 2 is the class, 3 is certified or not.

Answer (score 0):

Select the other table, INSERT > PivotTable with `name` in ROWS, `class` in COLUMNS, `certified` in FILTERS and in VALUES as Count of. Select PivotTable, HOME > Cells, Format, Format Cells..., Custom:

```
[=1]"X";General
```

<kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Being a PivotTable it will require a refresh to update.